# Compare two values in a single column to show and increment or decrement in valueas an indicator in ssrs

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

How do we compare two rows of a column and say which is grater? I need to put an indicator for this. Can this be done by an expression ?

```
dataset1
COmlumn2  column1
          -------
june       60.30
march      60.80
april      60.70
january    60.09
```

I want to select the previous 2 motnhs (taking the current month) and compare the values (to see which is greater) and mark an indicator accordingly in the SSRS table

Can we write an expression for this or do we need a different table(dataset2).
If we need to put this in dataset2 then how can i use both of these in a single table in a report.

```
---------------------------------
shopList   Target graph   status
shop1     (sparkline of     Increased (indicator)
           column2 in
           above table)
```

Comment: It is not clear from your post what you want to achieve, perhaps if you can mock a report and show how you want the column to be calculated, that would help. In general if you want to access data from previous row just use Previous function: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200.aspx.

Comment: I was not aware of the previous function. i will use this then .. this solves my problem